# Uninstall Intel Graphics for Linux 1.20 on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, intel-graphics, minecraft

I recently installed Intel's Graphics Drivers for Linux in my Ubuntu machine sometime last two weeks ago. So then yesterday, I played Minecraft after some months and noticed that it goes to 100% CPU after some time (5mins after starting the game or so, and this doesn't happen a month ago) . I tried a bunch of tests including changing `intel_pstate` CPU governors, tinkering settings in Minecraft, and now I am suspecting Intel's Graphics Drivers as the culprit. I want to test it out and uninstall the installed/updated binaries by the Intel Graphics Installer. How can I revert it back to what are the drivers/binaries installed before installing Intel Graphics Drivers? (There are some old threads here but I'm still not very good with Ubuntu, I only began using last March and I'm not very sure whether I can still do what other threads suggested on my 15.04 machine)

Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have the same question. Nobody's answering it. I've posted at Ubuntu Forums but am getting no satisfaction. But, I think the answer to your question is this:

http://theclonker.de/?p=89

You will have to modify the commands for your release. (Look for the line --->  Pin: release a=vivid*) Then, find out what dkms package you're using:

```
dpkg --list *dkms
```

You should get something like this:

**ii  i915-4.0.4-3.19-dkms**

So if, like me, you're using 15.04 (vivid), then you're probably using the same dkms package. And so:

Open a new Terminal (CTRL+Alt+T) and execute

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apt/preferences.d/intel-removal
```

Paste this code in the File and save it (don't forget to change the Ubuntu version if you're not using **vivid**):

```
    Package: *
    Pin: release a=vivid*
    Pin-Priority: 1001

    Package: *
    Pin: origin download.01.org
    Pin-Priority: -100
```

And then (don't forget to change the **dkms package** below if it's not the same):

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

sudo rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/intel-removal

sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/intellinuxgraphics.list*

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get purge i915-4.0.4-3.19-dkms intel-linux-graphics-installer
```

Comment: So basically, what's done here was to set the Intel's source's priority low so that I can get again those provided in the Ubuntu's repositories, then update my machine's source list and purge the graphics installer's files (if I understand it right). I've seen before the site you have mentioned but I have not tried it because the guide was meant for an older release. Thanks for the help! I can't try it now but looks like this will work fine. Thanks.

Comment: This procedure worked for me as of Sept 2016 on Ubuntu 16.04, of course using xenial as the distribution name. Seems to have rolled everything back very nicely. Thanks for taking the time to write this up!